# Function available throughout all Win Forms

Tags: c#

Very new to C# - moving from really admin in Powershell and Java. I am using the MS function to Decrypt files:

```
static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        //A 64 bit key and IV is required for this provider.
        //Set secret key For DES algorithm.
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        //Set initialization vector.
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

        //Create a file stream to read the encrypted file back.
        FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
           FileMode.Open,
           FileAccess.Read);
        //Create a DES decryptor from the DES instance.
        ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
        //Create crypto stream set to read and do a 
        //DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
        CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
           desdecrypt,
           CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        //Print the contents of the decrypted file.
        StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
        fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
        fsDecrypted.Flush();
        fsDecrypted.Close();
    }
```

And at the moment, I am calling it in a variety of buttons via in all different forms:

```
        string decryptionKey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ThickClient\secretKey.skey");
        DecryptFile("C:\\ThickClient\\Encrypted.enc", "C:\\ThickClient\\tempPWDump.enc", decryptionKey);
        string decryptedPW = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ThickClient\tempPWDump.enc");
        File.Delete(@"C:\ThickClient\tempPWDump.enc");
```

And I am having to define the `static void DecryptFile {code}` in each Form, and call it to a new variable in each form to utilise it. Seems crazy, where in the Windows forms can I define it and set a global variable so it is available to every form?

Comment: make a PUBLIC static Decrypter class?

Comment: Where is that defined, in any form? And is that for the variable or the function?

Comment: see Shadow Wizard's excellent answer below. Just be careful about that global (aka, public) variables you choose to add. Should forms know/set the type of coding? most likely no, they should (i would prefer) just be able to call the Decrypt() method of a the public (global) class and let that take care of the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a public static class. To do this, right click the project and choose Add → Class. In the dialog give name such as "Utils.cs" and confirm. Change the code to something like this:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now anywhere in the project, in any form, you can have:

```
Utils.DecryptFile(...);
```

In case you have several projects, it becomes bit more complicated but still pretty simple. Just put that class inside new Project of type Class Library and wherever you need the utilities, add reference to that project.

On a side note, to have a variable publicly available just add something like this to the class above: (known as static getter)

```
private static string decryptedPW = "";
public static string DecryptedPW
{
    get
    {
        //need to initialize?
        if (decryptedPW.Length == 0)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\ThickClient\tempPWDump.enc";
            decryptedPW = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        return decryptedPW;
    }
}
```

Then to access it from anywhere in the project:

```
string decryptedPW =  Utils.DecryptedPW;
```

Comment: How about global variables?

Comment: And then go for a C# book.

Comment: @FrK not relevant, we're talking about method not variables. In theory you can put the method in one existing form and reference it from the others, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: @VahidND yep, but finding this in a book will take hours, think it's totally legit to ask for a shortcut.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would like the decryptedPW string I create in my above code, to be available throughout every form, sorry, where can I define that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're right, that's why I said 'THEN' .... and I suggest that because defining classes is very basic to programming in c#.

Comment: @VahidND cheers, it sounded like you intended to rebuke the OP - defining classes is basic, static classes not very basic. (Of course should be learned, but not as a first step :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually by defining classes I meant the 'right click the project and choose Add → Class ...'part. but no matter I just sold a book :)